# MVC: Keep alive or make the initial load super fast

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

**The goal is that I want my overall website response time to be instantaneous.**

The problem is that I do no have IIS access, my website is hosted using external service and I have no control to the IIS panel.

My current approach now is having a scheduled code that keeps my website alive. The problem with this only approach is the hosting service has an algorithm to shutdown all their hosted website like every some hours.

This is why I need to implement another approach which to warm up / pre-load the website each time it runs.

How to do this when there is no access to the IIS panel?

Comment: you could have some external app (not on your host provider), that could request regularly your website.

Comment: Just hit your website with a known URL to keep it alive.  The default timeout for an IIS AppPool is 20 minutes.  You may need to alter the period depending on how often they close unused pools

Answer (score 5):

The solution requires *no 3rd party sites; robots;* or *apps*, you merely write a very simple app yourself that periodically performs a trivial web function, perhaps a **REST GET**.  By performing this function say every few minutes not only do you guarentee that the IIS pool won't timeout and be cold for a client, but it also has the nice effect of ensuring your website is up and running in a **warm condition** (JIT'd; and running) ready for a real request for your non-heartbeat website requests.

e.g.

In your website expose a REST API, say `www.misspiggy.com/api/hiyaaaa` that does nothing other than to return HTTP **200 OK**.

By implemententing this in your ASP.NET app, any request to the above URL will cause your stopped or cold ASP.NET website to be JIT'd during:

1. first deployment (and even then only during a request is made to it)
2. after the IIS AppPool has timed out and needs to restart on demand

The client code that makes the REST request can be anything:

- a console app
- a Windows service
- WinForms/WPF app

The console app can be triggered to fire via Windows Task Scheduler say every 5 minutes thus saving you the hastle of building in a scheduler.

> My current approach now is having a scheduled code that keeps my website alive. The problem with this only approach is the hosting service has an algorithm to shutdown all their hosted website like every some hours

I suggest you set your ping period to be a matter of minutes rather than  hours.

### No admin access to server required

> The problem is that I do no have IIS access, my website is hosted using external service and I have no control to the IIS panel

It should be pointed out that this solution does not require you to install anything new on the server nor make any changes on the server.

### Azure

It is interesting to note that Azure *Application Insights* has **Availability Tests** that though designed for testing web site availability, can be used for this exact same purpose of keeping your website alive and warm ready to go for web clients.  In fact this is what I do for my web apps.

Doing so keeps response times and latency as low as possible.

[image]

Comment: Could you add steps to set up the application insights ping test?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do but a real simple solution is to use a website monitoring site something like statuscake or uptime robot there are a large number of them out there. You set them up call a page or pages on your website at set intervals to ensure it is still up this has the added bonus of keeping the site warm.

I would also precompile your mvc app if you arent already doing that.

HTH